# Basic Probability question based on at-least number of occurrences.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A baker put 500 raisins into dough, mixed well, and made 100 cookies. You take a random cookie. What is the probability of finding at least 4 raisins in it?

At first I thought the answer is $ \frac{497}{500} $ because then there would be atleast 4 raisins in a random cookie. But my problem is how do I take 100 cookies in to account?

Comment: It is unclear exactly how to model this situation.  One possible way of modeling this would be that we can label each raisin and each cookie and make the *assumption* that raisin $i$ is in cookie $j$ with probability $\frac{1}{100}$ and that this is independent of the location of other raisins.  This is *not* however a very good assumption since it would allow for possibilities such as all 500 raisins to be in a single cookie with positive probability, but 500 raisins take up more volume than a cookie should...

Comment: Ignoring this, it becomes a question on binomial probability that the cookie you pick has 3 or fewer raisins (eqivalently 4 or more).  The probability will be the same for all cookies, and in particular for the random cookie that you selected.

Comment: @JMoravitz So, are you suggesting that the probability is 1 because all the raisins are evenly distributed on the cookies since it is mixed well?

Comment: That too is a reasonable interpretation of the question but I doubt that is the intended interpretation since this is for a probability class (supposedly).  We can only really say that the expected number of raisins per cookie is 5 without more explicit information about what "mixing well" means mathematically

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. I figured the answer. Its using the binomial distribution. The answer is 0.735.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

(*Using the assumptions I gave in the comments above*)

What is the probability of flipping exactly zero heads when flipping five hundred unfair coins where the probability of heads for each was $\frac{1}{100}$?

What is the probability of flipping exactly one head in the same situation?  Two heads?  Three heads?

What then is the probability of flipping -*Four or more*- heads in the same situation?

[See Binomial Distribution on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

How do the questions about coins I pose here relate to your original question?

Comment: Is this solvable using the Binomial Distribution where I take the possibility of finding up to three raisins and subtract it from 1?

Comment: @banureddy Yes.  $\mathsf P(X\geq 4)=1-\mathsf P(X \leq 3)$